# Build Me A Pawn Wall!

Tags: chess, construction

I have a very unique chess construction task for you all today: Build me a pawn wall!

I challenge you to construct a game that ends with both sides having 6 pawns on a file. This means that 6 white pawns on alligned on one file and 6 black pawns on another.

Before you call this an impossible task, I will let you know that I have found it myself to be possible for I have proven it possible already.

Comment: Bonus points if you get the other side to pay for it.

Comment: @jafe Hahahahaha omg i'm dying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to reduce it to 34 moves.
I can't prove this is optimal but I can't seem to get any lower using this strategy.

> 1. a4 h5 
>  2. g4 b5 
>  3. axb5 hxg4 
>  4. Nf3 Nc6 
>  5. bxc6 gxf3 
>  6. Nc3 Nf6 
>  7. Ne4 Nd5 
>  8. Nf6+ exf6 
>  9. Bh3 Nc3 
>  10. dxc3 Ba6 
>  11. Be6 Bd3 
>  12. exd3 dxe6 
>  13. Ra5 Rh4 
>  14. Rf5 Rc4 
>  15. dxc4 exf5 
>  16. h4 a5 
>  17. h5 a4 
>  18. h6 a3 
>  19. h7 a2 
>  20. h8=Q a1=Q 
>  21. Bf4 Qa5 
>  22. Qh4 Bc5 
>  23. Qd6 cxd6 
>  24. Be5 Be3 
>  25. fxe3 dxe5 
>  26. Qf4 Qc5 
>  27. b4 g5 
>  28. bxc5 gxf4 
>  29. e4 Qd5 
>  30. exd5 e4 
>  31. Rf1 Rc8 
>  32. d6 e3 
>  33. Rf2 Rc7 
>  34. dxc7 exf2+ *

Apronus link

> [Chess game, as above](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_h5_g4_b5_axb5_hxg4_Nf3_Nc6_bxc6_gxf3_Nc3_Nf6_Ne4_Nd5_Nf6*_exf6_Bh3_Nc3_dxc3_Ba6_Be6_Bd3_exd3_dxe6_Ra5_Rh4_Rf5_Rc4_dxc4_exf5_h4_a5_h5_a4_h6_a3_h7_a2_h8ZQ_a1ZQ_Bf4_Qa5_Qh4_Bc5_Qd6_cxd6_Be5_Be3_fxe3_dxe5_Qf4_Qc5_b4_g5_bxc5_gxf4_e4_Qd5_exd5_e4_Rf1_Rc8_d6_e3_Rf2_Rc7_dxc7_exf2*)

Comment: @RewanDemontay Finding the fastest is certainly a challenge. I could probably get my current tally down a few moves but couldn't be sure when it would be the best. Do you know the fastest way?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick sweep of the chess.com forums, and found a sweet, optimal 31.5 mover.

Credit goes to our very own Remellion here on SE for finding this solution!
https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/how-many-distinct-chess-games-are-possible-and-which-is-the-longest?page=7

> 1. b4 g5 2. h4 a5 3. hxg5 axb4 4. c4 f5 5. Rh4 Ra3 6. Re4 Re3 7. dxe3 fxe4 8. Nc3 Nf6 9. gxf6 Bh6 10. a4 Bf4 11. a5 h5 12. a6 h4 13. a7 h3 14. a8=Q b5 15. Ra6 h2 16. Rd6 exd6 17. Qc6 dxc6 18. exf4 h1=Q 19. g4 Qf3 20. exf3 Rh7 21. Be3 Rf7 22. Bc5 dxc5 23. Qc2 bxc3 24. Ne2 Qd5 25. cxd5 Bf5 26. Nc1 Nd7 27. Bc4 Nf8 28. Nd3 Ne6 29. gxf5 exd3 30. dxe6 dxc2 31. Ke2 bxc4 32. exf7+